# New Macbook Pro with three 27" monitors

Tags: hdmi, macbook-pro, external-display

I'm trying to get a three 27" Dell monitors setup with my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports). I bought the three adapters and have them going to the monitors with HDMI inputs. However I can only seem to get 2 monitors operating simultaneously.

There isn't much information online about this and the details are pretty scattered so I'm at a loss on how to get it working. :-/

Comment: Your best bet is to ask Apple about the Mac GPU limitation. As an anecdotal evidence, I bought a MacBook Air, and a docking station, hoping with the docking station I can use 2 monitors, but it looks like it was the MacBook air itself is the limitation and I can only use 1 monitor (so laptop + 1 external monitor) - despite the docking station supports 2 output. So it could be the MacBook Pro GPU not supporting more than 3 total display (1 laptop, 2 external).

Answer (score 1):

[Everymac](http://www.everymac.com) is about the best resource there is for this type of information on any Mac model.

For [your machine specifically](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.9-13-late-2016-retina-display-touch-bar-specs.html), it states...

> *In addition to simultaneous support of the internal display, this model supports a maximum resolution up to 4096x2304 at 60 Hz at over a
>   billion colors on two external displays or a single external display
>   at a maximum resolution up to 5120x2880 at 60 Hz at over a billion
>   colors via Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C).

They have a side article, based on user tests rather than official sources, [How many external displays can the Retina Display MacBook Pro models support? What is the maximum supported resolution of each? Are adapters required?](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-manually-switch-graphics.html#extdisplays) where someone did manage to get 3 screens running on a 2012 MacBook Pro, but it overheated badly.